# ROW_NUMBER() with Qualify clause in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

```
select a.pm_id, a.pm_name
from loc_table a
qualify row_number() over(partition by pm_id order by pm_name asc) =1;
```

Can we write it this way in Vertica, I tried it but the qualify keyword is not taken by Vertica and the from Clause has to be at the end.
Can anybody explain what the above query does and how can we achieve the same in Vertica.

Answer (score 2):

Vertica does not have the `QUALIFY` clause.

What it does have, is the *analytic limit clause*

Re-write your query like below, and run an easy global search-replace if you need that often:

```
SELECT 
  a.pm_id
, a.pm_name
FROM loc_table a
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY pm_id ORDER BY pm_name ASC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery in Vertica:

```
select pm_id, pm_name
from (select l.pm_id, l.pm_name,
             row_number() over (partition by pm_id order by pm_name asc) as seqnum
      from loc_table l
     ) l
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is pretty much exactly what `qualify` does.  Just like `having` filters on aggregation columns, `qualify` filters on window functions.

Comment: Actually I have to implement with qualify clause. can you please help me to achieve with qualify clause

Comment: @nodev_101 . . . Then use a database such as Teradata that supports the clause.  You can't use something not supported by the database you are using.